# What's the appropriate syntax for the view when the model accepts nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm working on a projects where hunts a list of tasks associated with them. I've got a hunts model that accepts nested attributes for the tasks model.   But I can't my views to work right.  Here's what my views/hunts.html.erb looks like:

```
    <h1>New Hunt</h1>

    <%= form_for(@hunt) do |f| %>       
      <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
        <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |builder| %>
        <%= render "task_fields", :f => builder %>
        <% end %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Add hunt" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Rails thinks that tasks_fields is located in the hunts views.  This is the error message I receive.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Hunts#new
Showing /****/app/views/hunts/new.html.erb where line #9 raised:
Missing partial hunts/task_fields, application/task_fields with {:handlers=>[:erb,   :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
 *****/app/views"
```

How do I tell rails to look in views/tasks instead of views/hunts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the name of the other folder, e.g.

```
<%= render "tasks/task_fields", :f => builder %>
```

will render tasks/_task_fields.html.erb

Comment: Thanks!  That was a mega-simple solution toa problem that had been vexing me for hours. Thank you so much for helping me get my app working!